# Border radius property | incorrect display on iPad but not iMAC

Tags: html, css, safari

Went around the apple store to test my site and noticed that the iPad put rounded borders on all my corners instead of only the two I specify.

Related code:

.
.
.

```
    <div id="wr_un_pass" >
      <input name="pass" id="un_pass" type="password" maxlength="20" >
      <p id="un_pass_lab" class="un_lab">Password</p>
      <p id="un_but">SignUp</p>
      <p id="un_rc">SignUp</p>
    </div>
  </form>
   <div id="un_rb" class="i_box_r" ><p id="un_rt" >Please enter all fields</p></div>
</div>
<style>
#un_pass{
  border-top-left-radius:  4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:  4px;  
  width:  200px;
  height:  29px;
  color:  #888887;
  border:  1px solid #cccccc;
  font-size:  18px;
}
```

.
.
.

Comment: What the hell? +1, just because I admire your approach to inventive cross-platform testing! =)

Comment: why is the `<style>` below the rest of the markup code?

Comment: radius is automatic on all input fields for the new iPad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new iPad automatically puts a radius on all my input fields.  Verified by removing radius property all together.

Comment: If thats correct what would be the solution? This means we cannot individually assign border raduis to the input fields as we wish on the ipad? I suppose there is a workaround... I have the same problem, could you let me know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should put the style above the html code, and you may also need webkits for iPad.

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
```

good luck!

Comment: well, it's worth trying, but I'd be surprised if the brand new devices he's testing on in the Apple Store need the vendor prefix.

Comment: radius is automatically inserted to all input fields.